# generate BZHI instruction with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to make `gcc` generate the [`bzhi` instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BZHI.html), part of BMI2,
*without* using intrinsics,
in order to create a portable code.

Given the outcome of `bzhi`, I expected that objective to be relatively accessible.
The [following SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31957340/646947) provides a code example, simplified below :

```
unsigned bzhi32(unsigned value, int nbBits)
{
    return value & ((1u << nbBits) - 1);
}
```

`clang` has no problem generating `bzhi` instruction with it, while I haven't found any similar outcome for `gcc` so far : 
https://godbolt.org/g/jYrh8F

I was wondering if this was possible.
This capability was [at least requested](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65871), but not sure if it was completed.
If it was, maybe there are just some subtle issues in the code snippet, for example with type or properties, which could be fixed to succeed this transformation with `gcc`.

*edit* : added `u` for constant, as suggested by @chux. It marginally changes the outcome for `gcc`, though it's still a 4-instructions function without `bzhi`.

Comment: Note: shifting unsigned values is usually less problematic: Add `u` `(1u << nbBits)-1`.  Note the [following SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31957340/646947) used an _unsigned_ 1 and not an `int` 1.

Comment: If you can't covert the compiler to do what you want and if an `#ifdef` is not suitable, then at some point, you'll have to choose between portability and performance - as they are so often conflicting goals.

Comment: I'm currently `#ifdef`'ing, trying to find a better solution.

Comment: Gcc ifuncs might work out well for this - are they OK portability-wise?

Comment: nope unfortunately, ifuncs are too `gcc` centric. Even `#ifdef` look preferable.

Comment: Make your special functions (function wrappers) `static inline`, stick them in a separate header file with `#ifdef` magic that ends up including a hardware-specific sub-header file just like gcc/icc/clang implement intrinsics, and be satisfied. It is the best option in my experience, especially for end-user-admins, who know their hardware, and can tune your code to their hardware. Remember: portability does not require "works perfectly off the shelf"; it is usually better to make it work *correctly* on any architecture, and also easy to tune to any architecture.

Comment: The bugzilla issue you link to was mostly about wrong flag handling. Asking for several things in the same report doesn't work. You may want to open a new problem report for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This optimization is not implemented in gcc as of January 2018 (there is a [feature request](https://gcc.gnu.org/PR82298)). You can get the instruction by using intrinsics:

```
#include <x86intrin.h>

unsigned bzhi32(unsigned value, int nbBits) {
   return _bzhi_u32(value, nbBits);
}
```